# Help needed in Exception class : Required fields are missing: [Account Name]

Tags: apex, visualforce, exception, dmlexception

[image]

As in the above pic shows, I don't want to display the System error message which i rounded in pic. How can i make disable it? I want to display only the message what we used generally in `ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.error,'Error Message'));`. I can make this possible by using if - else condition (Please see the code which i used made it). but i want get it through using try - catch blocks only. And also please tell me that how we are getting `Required fields are missing: [Account Name]` message. Is that system validation rule or any other error message?

You can also see the code which i have used.

```
    public void comittedResult() {
        try{
        aOne=[select id,name,phone,Industry from Account where ID=:accid];
       /* if (String.isBlank(accName)){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.error,'Please enter account name'));
        }//!(accPhone.isNumeric())
        else if(!(pattern.matches('[0-9]+',accPhone))){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.error,'Please enter correct phone number'));
        }
        else  {*/
        aOne.name = accName;
        aOne.phone = accPhone;
        update aOne;
        displayPopup = false;
        reflectRecords();
   //   }
     }catch(DMLException e){
         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.error,'Please enter Name'));
     }
     }
```

Comment: @Kumaar, if you're using an `apex:inputField` element you can simply add `required="true"` attribute to it, and it will not allow name to be blank and it will save unnecessary server operation.

Comment: KS Kumaar.. Can you please closed this question by accepting that answer which you used as your solution.

Comment: Yeah Ratan, Still i am finding for exact solution where the following solutions giving hints only. Definitely i will close it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have this field not blank you can achieve this using the visualforce `required='true'` attribute.

So if you have:

`<apex:inputText value='{!a.Name}'/>`

just change it to:

`<apex:inputText value='{!a.Name)' required='true'/>`

And it should validate that the name won't be blank, and won't send an unnecessary server-call and won't do an unnecessary DML operation.

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding the add error in the catch block. first, check the name is null or not

```
if(accName == null)
{
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.error,'Please enter Name'));
   return;
}
```

OR another way to show only one error message in page

```
catch(DMLException e){
    ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR, e.getdmlMessage(0) );
    ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
}
```

Comment: Hi Ratan, 
The same two messages are coming even by using e.getdmlMessage(0)

Comment: @KSKumaar with `e.getdmlMessage(0)` are you using `(ApexPages.severity.error,'Please enter Name')` this as well?

Comment: Yeah @Ratan. I am using it.

Comment: @KSKumaar dont' use both only use only one i.e. e.getdmlMessage(0)

Comment: I used only  e.getdmlMessage(0). But it is giving Required fields are missing: [Account Name]. This is system error message. right?

Comment: @KSKumaar yes right that's why I gave another option to check if `accName == null` then show error message and return

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43625/discussion-between-ks-kumaar-and-ratan).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(accName == null || accName == '') {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.error,'Please enter Name'));
}
```

OR

```
catch(DMLException e){
    if(e.getMessage().contains('Required fields are missing')){
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please Enter Account Name');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
    }
}
```